# Singletons vs Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

This question is not about the technical problem, but rather the approach.

I know two more or less common approaches to store the data received from the server in your app:

1) Using managers, data holders etc to store the data. They are most often some kind of singleton and are used to store the models received from the server. (E.g. - the array of the posts/places/users) Singletons are needed to be able to access the data from any screen. I think the majority of apps uses this approach.

2) Using Core Data (or maybe Realm) as in-memory storage. This approach avoids having singletons, but, I guess, it is a bit more complex (and crash risky) to maintain and support.

How do you store data and why?

P.S. Any answers would help. But big "thank you" for detailed ones, with reasons.

Answer (score 6):

The reason people opt to use Core Data/Relam/Shark or any other iOS ORM is mainly for the purpose of **persisting** data between runs of the app.

Currently there are two ways of doing this, for single values and very small (not that I encourage it) objects you can use the `UserDefaults` to persist between app launches. For a approach closer to a database, infact in the case of Core Data and SharkORM, they are built on top of SQLite, you need to use an ORM.

Using a manager to store an array of a data models will only persist said models for the lifetime of the app. For example when the user force quits the app, restarts their device or in some circumstances when iOS terminates your app, all that data will be lost permanently. This is because it is stored in RAM which is volatile memory, rather than in a database on the disk itself.

Using a database layer even if you don't specifically require persistence between launches can have its advantages though; for instance SharkORM allows you to execute raw SQL queries on your objects if you don't want to use the built in powerful query builder. This can be useful to quickly pull the model you are interested in rather than iterating through a local array.

In reply to your question, how do *I* store data?
Well, I use a combination of all three. Say for instance I called to an API for some data which I wanted to display there and then to the user, I would use a manager instance with an array to hold the data model.
But on the flipside if I wanted to store that data for later or if I needed to execute a complex query on it, I would store it on disk using Shark.
If however I just wanted to store whether or not the user had seen my on boarding flow I would just persist a boolean value into `UserDefaults`.

I hope this is detailed enough for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I am trying to do is I want to decide for myself: Do I want to use Core Data (without the need to persist data between app launches) just for the sake of avoiding singletons. Or are singletons okay there as managing core data (or any other orm) can take too much effort.

Comment: There is some controversy surrounding the use of singletons but here is my opinion as an experienced iOS dev: Singletons are fine, and infact for the role of a data source/manager they are the best solution. There is only one instance so it is kept nice and lightweight and the data is there and easily accessible. You shouldn't add the extra overhaul of having to read data from a disk (which is MUCH slower than RAM) if you don't have to as this will be far more resource intensive than keeping a singleton in memory. Do however empty the array of objects when you are done with them.

Comment: My experience is exactly the opposite, singletons are by definition a memory leak and lazy programmers use them to avoid having to think about object lifetime. Not acceptable for professional code. One can get the same results by hanging a ref to an object off of the app delegate without introducing ref count loops that cannot be deallocated

Answer (score 2):

CoreData isn't strictly "in-memory". You can load objects into your data model and save them into their context, then they might actually be on disk and out of main memory, and they can easily be brought back via fetch requests.

Singletons, on the other hand, do typically stay in main memory all the time until the user terminates the app.  If you have larger objects that you are storing in some data structure (e.g. full resolution images when all you really needed was a thumbnail), this can be quite a resource hog.